# onClick jQuery Function not Trigging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make this simples onclick work... But in my file.js 80% of them work and this one (for example) don't!

If someone could just help me out...

Function:

```
    jQuery(document).on("click", '#avatarGO', function(event){

toastr.clear();

jQuery('#avatarGO').addClass('disabled');

jQuery('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');

var formData = $("#changeAvatarForm").serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : '../../class/profile/change_avatar.php',
    data        : formData,
    dataType    : 'json'
})
.done(function(data) {

    console.log(data);

    if (!data.success){

        //Failure
        jQuery.each(data.sysemp, function(index, value){

          jQuery('#'+value+'').addClass('has-error');

        });

        //Failure
        jQuery.each(data.syserr, function(index, value){

           toastr["error"](value);

        });

        jQuery('#avatarGO').removeClass('disabled');

    } else {

        //Success
        toastr["success"](data.message);
        setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 850);

    }

});

event.preventDefault();
```

});

HTML:

```
<button id="avatarGO" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Confirmar</button>
```

Full File: https://www.ertheya.com/assets/plugins/kCore.js

Updates:

The console isnt showing errors
The form onClick isnt triggered
The HTML is correct

Comment: please describe exactly what doesn't work, paste any errors, explain any unexpected behavior, etc.

Comment: The console don't display any error;

Comment: then add that to your question -- the more clear information you supply in your question, the likelier it is to be answered and not downvoted

Comment: It should, when the button is clicked trigger this ajax form! But nothing happens! Not event in Chrome "Networking" tab apears the form submit...

Comment: @Creos It worked on my localhost perfectly once I transfer to the Web Server some stuff didn't work..

Comment: @charlietfl the page is not reloading..

Comment: so add all of this extra information from the comments into your question (you can edit your question in stackoverflow)

Comment: Share your html content also

Comment: ReferenceError: toastr is not defined, i got this error. When i include your js. toastr is not declared inside your click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code inside document.ready and check it. Hope you are not getting errors in console.

Comment: Hi! I'll try, but no errors on console.. That's my issue! The ajax is not event submitted! I've checked the html and I should trigger the AvatarGO ID on ciick

Comment: Yeah.. same issue... It isn't triggered!

Comment: Share your html content also

Comment: ReferenceError: toastr is not defined, i got this error. When i include your js. toastr is not declared inside your click handler.